# How do I calculate what % of price hits R1 before pivot

Tags: statistics, technical-analysis

I am trying to calculate what % of times the price touches R1 before the pivot level.

I have the data for the last 10 years and know how often it touches the R1 one and pivot point but I don't know how to calculate when one is touched before the other.

Any hint will be appreciated.